# Unable to debug a backgroundtask

Tags: c#, windows, microsoft-metro

I have created a timer background task to run for every 15 mins. the task is being run for every 15 mins but it is showing a errors in error log. The below error is shown in error log.

Activation of app 5ff2e7ca-c909-4a8a-bc6c-199d3bca12d9_cj7gm2frb8y4m!App failed with error: A device attached to the system is not functioning. See the Microsoft-Windows-TWinUI/Operational log for additional information.

unable to debug the background task

Comment: Add some code please, you should be able to debug background threads

Comment: have you tried attaching to the XDE.exe process?

Answer (score 0):

Same Problem. I was able to debug the task earlier however during switching from Debug to Release mode and back to Debug mode and changing WMD to DLL to WMD, this problem appeared.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem and solved it by "adding a reference".[image: Property page showing references in background sample]
I saw this mentioned once or twice in the docs and assumed it just meant adding a build dependency, but that is not enough.  You have to explicitly add the background task project (called "Tasks" above) reference to the main project (called BackgroundTask above).

Comment: Where is this dialogue? It looks like a C++ project one, which isn't relevant to this (C#) question.

Answer (score -1):

What do you mean by 'background task'? Is it a Windows Service? Is it just a non-service app which runs in background without a UI - a Win32 application, for example? Which OS?

There are a couple of ways to hook an app to a debugger. One is open your project in Visual Studio - Debug Menu -> Attach to Process. Or put a DebugBreak and when the app shows a "Abort/Retry/Cancel" dialog, hit retry and attach to debugger.

Comment: I created a metro application. And also created a time trigger background task to run for every 15 mins. the background task gets the data and that is used to update the live tile. I have tried by attaching process during debug but that also didn't work. A device attached to the system is not functioning error is thrown

Comment: You can't use the word metro anymore
http://gizmodo.com/5931381/windows-metro-isnt-metro-anymore